# Mapping pictures in CSS PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, image, embed

I have a plugin which is importing some products. But the problem is that the plugin only supports "gallery pictures". This is the reason why you don't see any title picture:

https://gamekeys-shop.de/produkt/battlefield-1/

Is there a way to map the gallery picture to the title picture with CSS?
Or is there another way?

Furthermore it would be very good if I can also delete the link from the gallery picture so that I have only one outgoing link and not two if the gallery picture is mapped to the title picture.

Is there a way to do this?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Not sure I've understood but if you want to show the product title (Battlefield 1) somewhere else, you could use jQuery to target the element with the title in it (e.g. `$('.product-title').val()`) then write that to some other element on the page.

Comment: No, I want to display the gallery picture as main picture. Where the placeholder picture is currently.

Comment: So why not just output the appropriate image url where you want the image to appear? This isn't a CSS issue; it's that the path to the image is not the one you want. Your CMS may offer the facility to change it, or you may need to change your code in the template. But all it's down to is putting the correct `<img src="">` tag in.

Comment: As I wrote... that's not possible with the plugin... :/